# Having problem with google_mlkit_image_labeling in fluter

Tags: flutter, machine-learning, model, google-mlkit

I am deploying my ml model in flutter app but whenever in put google_mlkit_image_labeling dependence in pub get and run my code it shown this error:
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
E/FlutterLoader(19847): Flutter initialization failed.
E/FlutterLoader(19847): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.thegrowzone-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.thegrowzone-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.thegrowzone-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
E/FlutterLoader(19847):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:94)
E/FlutterLoader(19847):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:164)
E/FlutterLoader(19847):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.ensureInitializationComplete(FlutterLoader.java:239)
E/FlutterLoader(19847):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine.(FlutterEngine.java:327)
E/FlutterLoader(19847):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine.(FlutterEngine.java:207)
E/FlutterLoader(19847):     at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.setupFlutterEngine(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:272)
E/FlutterLoader(19847):     at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onAttach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:181)
E/FlutterLoader(19847):     at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:495)
E/FlutterLoader(19847):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6760)
E/FlutterLoader(19847):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
E/FlutterLoader(19847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
E/FlutterLoader(19847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
E/FlutterLoader(19847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
E/FlutterLoader(19847):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
E/FlutterLoader(19847):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/FlutterLoader(19847):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
E/FlutterLoader(19847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)

How showed i solve this problem and i also tried tflite package it did not work. if anyone knows any other way to deploy ml model in flutter please tell

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing `libflutter.so`.
Could you check whether you configs are set properly?